# Use Zlib library to compress large include files experience?

Tags: php, large-files, zlib

I'm interesting in experience of others developers with Zlib, and compressing large files, and how it will depends on application processes, is that going to make application slower, or not, or will decrease any other application performance. 
If there is any other better solution shoot.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on serverfault.

Comment: Is your application IO bound or CPU bound? If the former, then zlib will help. Note that you can only use zlib for sequential files that aren't already compressed.

Answer (score 1):

Large is relative, but if you have a lot of server threads they will be using more CPU doing decompression of course. It depends on how many concurrent downloads of those files you have and what your servers can handle. Try to stress-test it and see how it performs.

Also if you can use zlib in a streaming mode with php that would probably help.